# Pyinstaller python to .exe not showing any output on the commandline interface

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, pip, pyinstaller

I used pyinstaller V 4.1 to convert a python 3.9 script to .exe. The build did finish but opening up the
application would just open up a blank screen. The script is text based and commandline only. The command I used is `pyinstaller --onefile 'p_script.py'`. I tried uninstalling pyinstaller and reinstalling it with
admin cmd but to no avail.

Here is the warn file:

```
This file lists modules PyInstaller was not able to find. This does not
necessarily mean this module is required for running you program. Python and
Python 3rd-party packages include a lot of conditional or optional modules. For
example the module 'ntpath' only exists on Windows, whereas the module
'posixpath' only exists on Posix systems.

Types if import:
* top-level: imported at the top-level - look at these first
* conditional: imported within an if-statement
* delayed: imported from within a function
* optional: imported within a try-except-statement

IMPORTANT: Do NOT post this list to the issue-tracker. Use it as a basis for
           yourself tracking down the missing module. Thanks!

missing module named 'win32com.gen_py' - imported by win32com (conditional, optional), C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py (top-level)
missing module named org - imported by copy (optional)
missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap (delayed), importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), zipimport (top-level)
excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), zipimport (top-level), PyInstaller.loader.pyimod02_archive (delayed)
missing module named pep517 - imported by importlib.metadata (delayed)
missing module named grp - imported by subprocess (optional), shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed, optional), distutils.archive_util (optional)
missing module named pwd - imported by posixpath (delayed, conditional), subprocess (optional), shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed, conditional, optional), http.server (delayed, optional), webbrowser (delayed), netrc (delayed, conditional), getpass (delayed), distutils.util (delayed, conditional, optional), distutils.archive_util (optional)
missing module named urllib.pathname2url - imported by urllib (conditional), PyInstaller.lib.modulegraph._compat (conditional)
missing module named _posixsubprocess - imported by subprocess (optional), multiprocessing.util (delayed)
missing module named _posixshmem - imported by multiprocessing.resource_tracker (conditional), multiprocessing.shared_memory (conditional)
missing module named multiprocessing.set_start_method - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.get_start_method - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.get_context - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level), multiprocessing.managers (top-level), multiprocessing.sharedctypes (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.TimeoutError - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level)
missing module named _scproxy - imported by urllib.request (conditional)
missing module named termios - imported by tty (top-level), getpass (optional)
missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform (delayed, optional), xml.sax._exceptions (conditional)
missing module named multiprocessing.BufferTooShort - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.AuthenticationError - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
missing module named asyncio.DefaultEventLoopPolicy - imported by asyncio (delayed, conditional), asyncio.events (delayed, conditional)
missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform (delayed, optional)
missing module named java - imported by platform (delayed)
missing module named _winreg - imported by platform (delayed, optional), pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed, conditional)
missing module named readline - imported by cmd (delayed, conditional, optional), code (delayed, conditional, optional), pdb (delayed, optional)
missing module named 'org.python' - imported by pickle (optional), xml.sax (delayed, conditional), setuptools.sandbox (conditional)
missing module named posix - imported by os (conditional, optional), shutil (conditional)
missing module named resource - imported by posix (top-level), test.support (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named pyimod03_importers - imported by C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgres.py (top-level)
missing module named 'com.sun' - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named com - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed)
missing module named 'pkg_resources.extern.pyparsing' - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.requirements (top-level), pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.markers (top-level)
missing module named __builtin__ - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing (conditional), setuptools._vendor.pyparsing (conditional)
missing module named ordereddict - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing (optional), setuptools._vendor.pyparsing (optional)
missing module named _manylinux - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.tags (delayed, optional), setuptools._vendor.packaging.tags (delayed, optional)
missing module named pkg_resources.extern.packaging - imported by pkg_resources.extern (top-level), pkg_resources (top-level)
missing module named pkg_resources.extern.appdirs - imported by pkg_resources.extern (top-level), pkg_resources (top-level)
missing module named Quartz - imported by pygetwindow._pygetwindow_macos (top-level), pyautogui._pyautogui_osx (optional)
missing module named 'Xlib.XK' - imported by pyautogui._pyautogui_x11 (top-level)
missing module named 'Xlib.ext' - imported by pyautogui._pyautogui_x11 (top-level)
missing module named Xlib - imported by mouseinfo (conditional), pyautogui._pyautogui_x11 (top-level)
missing module named 'Xlib.display' - imported by pyautogui._pyautogui_x11 (top-level)
missing module named AppKit - imported by pyperclip (delayed, conditional, optional), pyautogui._pyautogui_osx (top-level)
missing module named Tkinter - imported by pymsgbox (conditional, optional), mouseinfo (conditional, optional)
missing module named 'rubicon.objc' - imported by mouseinfo (conditional)
missing module named rubicon - imported by mouseinfo (conditional)
missing module named PIL - imported by pyscreeze (conditional, optional), mouseinfo (conditional, optional)
missing module named Foundation - imported by pyperclip (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named PyQt4 - imported by pyperclip (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named PyQt5 - imported by pyperclip (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named qtpy - imported by pyperclip (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named gtk - imported by pyperclip (delayed, conditional, optional)
runtime module named six.moves - imported by pynput._util (top-level)
missing module named StringIO - imported by Cryptodome.Util.py3compat (conditional), PyInstaller.lib.modulegraph._compat (conditional), PyInstaller.lib.modulegraph.zipio (conditional), six (conditional)
missing module named setuptools.extern.packaging - imported by setuptools.extern (top-level), setuptools.dist (top-level), setuptools.command.egg_info (top-level)
missing module named setuptools.extern.ordered_set - imported by setuptools.extern (top-level), setuptools.dist (top-level), setuptools.command.sdist (top-level)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.packaging.specifiers' - imported by setuptools.config (top-level)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.packaging.version' - imported by setuptools.config (top-level), setuptools.msvc (top-level)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.packaging.utils' - imported by setuptools.wheel (top-level)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.packaging.tags' - imported by setuptools.wheel (top-level)
missing module named wincertstore - imported by setuptools.ssl_support (delayed, optional)
missing module named 'backports.ssl_match_hostname' - imported by setuptools.ssl_support (optional)
missing module named backports - imported by setuptools.ssl_support (optional)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.pyparsing' - imported by setuptools._vendor.packaging.requirements (top-level), setuptools._vendor.packaging.markers (top-level)
missing module named 'numpy_distutils.cpuinfo' - imported by numpy.f2py.diagnose (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named 'numpy_distutils.fcompiler' - imported by numpy.f2py.diagnose (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named 'numpy_distutils.command' - imported by numpy.f2py.diagnose (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named numpy_distutils - imported by numpy.f2py.diagnose (delayed, optional)
missing module named __svn_version__ - imported by numpy.f2py.__version__ (optional)
missing module named numarray - imported by numpy.distutils.system_info (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named Numeric - imported by numpy.distutils.system_info (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named _curses - imported by curses (top-level), curses.has_key (top-level)
missing module named dummy_threading - imported by numpy.distutils.misc_util (optional), numpy.distutils.ccompiler (optional)
missing module named hypothesis - imported by numpy._pytesttester (delayed)
missing module named 'nose.plugins' - imported by numpy.testing._private.noseclasses (top-level), numpy.testing._private.nosetester (delayed)
missing module named scipy - imported by numpy.testing._private.nosetester (delayed, conditional)
missing module named 'nose.util' - imported by numpy.testing._private.noseclasses (top-level)
missing module named nose - imported by numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed, optional), numpy.testing._private.decorators (delayed), numpy.testing._private.noseclasses (top-level)
missing module named psutil - imported by numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed, optional)
missing module named pytest - imported by numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.number - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.object_ - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.signbit - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.isnan - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.float32 - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.intp - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.lib.i0 - imported by numpy.lib (top-level), numpy.dual (top-level)
missing module named numpy.linalg.matrix_power - imported by numpy.linalg (top-level), numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix (top-level)
missing module named _dummy_thread - imported by numpy.core.arrayprint (optional)
missing module named numpy.core.integer - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.fft.helper (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.sqrt - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.conjugate - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.sign - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.divide - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.geterrobj - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.add - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.complexfloating - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.inexact - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.cdouble - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.csingle - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.double - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.single - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.linalg.inv - imported by numpy.linalg (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.linalg.lstsq - imported by numpy.linalg (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.linalg.eigvals - imported by numpy.linalg (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named pickle5 - imported by numpy.compat.py3k (optional)
missing module named numpy.recarray - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level)
missing module named numpy.dtype - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level), numpy.ctypeslib (top-level)
missing module named numpy.expand_dims - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.array - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.extras (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level), numpy.ctypeslib (top-level)
missing module named numpy.bool_ - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level)
missing module named numpy.iscomplexobj - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.amin - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.amax - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.ndarray - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.extras (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level), numpy.ctypeslib (top-level)
missing module named numpy.histogramdd - imported by numpy (delayed), numpy.lib.twodim_base (delayed)
missing module named numpy.eye - imported by numpy (delayed), numpy.core.numeric (delayed)
missing module named cffi - imported by Cryptodome.Util._raw_api (optional), win32ctypes.core (optional)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `—debug=all` to the build to get more debug info at runtime? Is there no error message at all? See https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html

Comment: Since the script is command line based, by "blank screen"  do you mean that the window keeps closing ? And also it'd be better if you could some part of the code rather than the warn file